# Is it possible to connect NodeMCU with Microsoft Azure Event Hub?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, azure-eventhub, nodemcu, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to send data from ESP8266 Nodemcu to Microsoft Azure using 'Event Hub'. while searching on the internet i am getting results were they are using Azure Iot Hub. Since my application does not require bi directional communication and also azure iot hub service is very expensive than azure event hub service i would prefer if it is possible to use Azure event hub with esp8266 Nodemcu .
can anybody direct me in the right direction.

Comment: Which IoT firmware do you use (Arduino, NodeMCU, MicroPython, ...)?

Comment: i use arduino ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the Event Hubs REST API for that.

- API documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/mt652149.aspx
- A proof of concept implementation with Arduino: https://www.hackster.io/stepanb/proof-of-concept-nodemcu-arduino-and-azure-event-hub-a33043
- Full-blown client implementation for Arduino: https://github.com/gloveboxes/Arduino-ESP8266-Secure-Azure-IoT-Hub-Client

Comment: Thank you @Marcel stor. The proof of concept implementation did worked fine with small modification and also the documentation helped a lot.

Comment: I was able to send events to event hub using nodemcu. but i am not able to send batch events. i followed the following link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-batch-events
but still was not able to send the events